# Typescript Generic Array to Record function with proper type restrictions

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to write a generic function that takes an `array: T[]` and a selector `K` and returns a `Record<T[K], T>` that maps each element in the array from one of its properties to itself.

e.g.

```
const input1 = [{ name: "Alice" }, { name: "Bob" }];
const output1: Record<string, { name: string }> = toRecord(input1, "name");
// { Alice: { name: "Alice" }, Bob: { name: "Bob" } }

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
enum Name {
  Alice = "Alice",
  Bob = "Bob"
}
const input2 = [{ name: Name.Alice }, { name: Name.Bob }];
const output2: Record<Name, { name: Name }> = toRecord(input2, "name");
// { Alice: { name: "Alice" }, Bob: { name: "Bob" } }

// -----------------------------------------------------------------
interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  sibling?: Person;
}
const input3: Person[] = [{ id: 1, name: "Alice" }, { id: 2, name: "Bob" }];
const output3: Record<number, Person> = toRecord(input3, "id");
// { 1: { id: 1, name: "Alice" }, 2: { id: 2, name: "Bob" } }
```

I can't figure out how to restrict the type of the selector property `K` so that `T[K]` has a type a `Record` accepts as keys i.e. `string | number | symbol`.

This is what I have so far:

```
export function toRecord<T, K extends keyof T>(
  array: T[], 
  selector: K
): Record<T[K], T> {
  return array.reduce(
    (acc, item) => (acc[item[selector]] = item, acc), 
    {} as Record<T[K], T>
  )
}
```

But this gives me the following error at `T[K]`:

> ```
> Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.      
>  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
>    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
>      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
>        Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
>          Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
>            Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
>              Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
>                Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
>                  Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.(2344)
> ```

How can I restrict `K` so that `T[K]` is `string | number | symbol`?

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-amxpca)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typescript doesn't know that the values of T are valid as keys.

> Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.

This is saying that `T` could be `{ a: boolean }` or `{ a: () => void }` and that would mean that `T[K]` could be a boolean or a function, neither of which are valid as object property names.

So I would constrain `T` to be an object with only values that are allowed to be keys:

```
function toRecord<
  T extends { [K in keyof T]: string | number | symbol }, // added constraint
  K extends keyof T
>(array: T[], selector: K): Record<T[K], T> {
  return array.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item[selector]] = item, acc), {} as Record<T[K], T>)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=13&pln=2&pc=53#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOAlAphOAnAJgHgFgAoRRAFUXQA8p0xcBnRAb0QG0BpRGJAa3QBPOMAoBdAFyJGUbLwDmiAD6IwIALYAjdNmXTBWuABtEAXwA0JMtxp0GzAcNHkSAPgAUAQ2zZPgqeTsYubS6EaYKNhSnACUUhhYePiBnMEUrqxWiNjoUCDYSN6+ggB0ObggEOjuXhAQITB06jGIALwZ7mwl3Z51IeyN6OrsjGEROGKSPE1mMSEspoiezAk4BClp5K4xJKYkJFhgMjxgAA4gUG0crKqe6uhSAOQAgkYwVY8hnvIPiACMACYzPNbvcngAhOCaT5LH5SAEAdjMiDEBwQxzgF3Ol1ayDQmDW7l42JCjzAd3Qjx2xDRR2M6BKRjg8ncmKg2JiQA)

---

It sounds like you have a properties which may not be eligible as keys. You can still strongly type that, just know that if the value of the property is an object, then it can't be a key, so those must be filtered out. As previously states, the type for an object property name is `string | number | symbol`. So lets keep those values, and discard the rest.

```
type RecordableKeys<T> = {
  // for each key in T
  [K in keyof T]:
    // is the value a valid object key?
    T[K] extends string | number | symbol
    // Yes, return the key itself
    ? K
    // No. Return `never`
    : never
}[keyof T] // Get a union of the values that are not `never`.

interface Person {
  name: string,
  age: number
  sibling?: Person
}

type PersonRecordableKeys = RecordableKeys<Person> // 'name' | 'age'
```

With that helper type in place, we can change the constraint of `T` in `toRecord` to:

```
function toRecord<
  T extends { [P in RecordableKeys<T>]: string | number | symbol },
  K extends RecordableKeys<T>
>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwIYCMA2EDSEIAzgDwAqAfFALxQDeAsAFBRQD0bUAZilBOvAAWUANaEoASwB2UMs1YBtPJJliQiLrIC6ALnmt2nCUSjBB0AG7psAV2jooV7BNRREmAFYJgowgH59VjIlLT4AD2AIKVQTImBkaQBzKAAfKCkbAFtMCGRUqCIQbMRsQMMoAE0IIgAaKGQIYBtkGTNoNUlgIghsLjK-KDwyjigAOUQAOlhG5pkAAykIC1y5sp10pdzmAF8FNQ1tcoBxRqgHGykJRBkDtsdrOxMzdB90BvTEHwXN5DmJ5mYXAu8GAV1aiDgSDQJH0ZHCkWiJjoUAUAAUVNMoRgcPhCKRKLoCvEkvkMtlcvlCsVsFBtjV9MoIBEojFMShsbgCMRyBRmBQABRvZDoEDrYJaOrdXAglDrPAASnWkPZ5BCdUo9H0DSaLTOyGFIAmDVQNngEH5gvg8DqEkimXlNCo-ORE1dAmtKNtEEyCil3hQWkJXsytPldTo2zOJmV0OCeAlsgo8p2AKY0kiyC4AmgqNyRGumpY6XQmQg6ziCSkiXpRfQiTL6SyOWQ+iIEhwST861zyHzUhTTGYSCkcRUYBswG7eeuClCtAU9GLpfWAHIAILOM0rup1hsARgATLTw0uGyuAELubdnevrA8AdlpUC0Q+uo8QE-HPlowAhCHZ-LSF+dQrlIJYQCuyZMMOo5MpAIIAKL6rwP5-ligFSMBUArm2HZVpB5S5MgspQPA6BSFIny+CAUCYDRlGqIQWC4PctgQKmMElBAEzYIgiT8h+wBflBQA)

Comment: I get the error `Index signature is missing in type ...` with this if the type I pass is an interface, see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1tnxca

Comment: Updated my answer. The `[K in keyof T]` now says it can only be indexed by its own known keys.

Comment: Thanks. Using `K` here again gives me the warning `Shadowed name: 'K' (no-shadowed-variable)` but using `[P in keyof T]` solves this. I still have to add `any` to the possible types though: `T extends { [P in keyof T]: string | number | symbol | any }`, because some of my interface properties can be Objects, see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9edxru

Comment: Well that gets a lot more complicated then. You couldn't allow `toRecord(input, 'sibling')` then, as you can't make an object a key in another object. See my edit

Comment: Wow, this works for all my cases. I was starting to think that those kind of type restrictions aren't possible. Sorry if I wasn't clear from the beginning. I was looking for a way to restrict `T[K]` to `string | number | symbol` and I guess that's it.

Comment: Happy to help. If you want to learn more about authoring advanced typescript types, [this article](https://hackernoon.com/learn-advanced-typescript-4yl727e6) was a huge help to me

Answer (score 3):

Typescript wants to know for sure that T is actually also a record:

```
export function toRecord<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], selector: K): Record<T[K], T> {
  return array.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [item[selector]]: item }), {} as Record<T[K], T>)
}
```

Comment: I would avoid use of `any` here as Typescript is alerting you of a potential issues if you have non-keyable values in `T`.